# Code not converting text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox that allows users to input a decimal values that then gets stored in the a table in the database, this piece of code works in the development environment. I have now published the my project to the server and now is not longer taking the values with the decimal places.

```
decimal ReceiptAmount;
decimal AmountDue;
decimal Change;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_ReceiptAmount")).Text))
{
    if (((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_ReceiptAmount")).Text.Contains(".") == true)
    {
        ReceiptAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_ReceiptAmount")).Text.Replace(".", ","));
    }
    else
    {
        ReceiptAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_ReceiptAmount")).Text);
    }
}
else
{
    ReceiptAmount = 0;
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_AmountDue")).Text))
{
    if (((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_AmountDue")).Text.Contains(".") == true)
    {
        AmountDue = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_AmountDue")).Text.Replace(".", ","));
    }
    else
    {
        AmountDue = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_AmountDue")).Text);
    }
}
else
{
    AmountDue = 0;
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_Change")).Text))
{
    if (((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_Change")).Text.Contains(".") == true)
    {
        Change = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_Change")).Text.Replace(".", ","));
    }
    else
    {
        Change = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_Change")).Text);
    }
}
else
{
    Change = 0;
}
```

I am not to sure what seems to be the problem with this piece of code. The Textbox are found in a datalist that I loop through to get all of the values.

Comment: kindly align your code

Comment: My eyes hurt so much

Comment: You seem to do a lot of manual culture changing on decimal to change the decimal separator, instead you should just parse it in whatever culture you need. As towards your actual question, what errors are you getting?

Comment: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value)

Comment: the error above is what I am getting back and I am not to sure how else to convert the string to deciaml.

Answer (score 1):

The `Convert.ToDecimal` overload that takes a string as input will parse the string using the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Probably your server has different regional settings. Depending on regional settings, a comma or point may be either interpreted as a thousand separator (and thus ignored) or as the decimal separator.

Instead, you should use `Decimal.Parse` directly, providing either a specific culture or the invariant culture, depending on your use case.

Ideally, you'd set the culture of the user somewhere. To achieve this there are multiple approaches, e.g. for ASP.Net Web forms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

If you parse the string using the correct culture, you can get rid of the string manipulation for replacing `.` with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lines like

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)dl_Item.FindControl("tb_ReceiptAmount")).Text))
```

look *very ugly*; let's *extract a method* (copy/paste is *very, very bad* practice):

```
  private String FindDLText(String controlName) {
    var box = dl_Item.FindControl(controlName) as TextBox;

    return box == null ? null : box.Text;
  }
```

Then you don't need checking `Text.Contains(".") == true`, just `Replace` if you really *need* it:

```
  private Decimal FindDLValue(String controlName) {
    String text = FindDLText(controlName); 

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
      return 0.0M;

    //TODO: check if you really need this
    //text = text.Replace(".", ",");

    // you have to specify Culture either InvariantCulture or some predefined one;
    // say, new CultureInfo("ru-RU") // <- use Russian Culture to parse this
    return Decimal.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
```

Finally, you can get

```
  decimal ReceiptAmount = FindDLValue("tb_ReceiptAmount");
  decimal AmountDue = FindDLValue("tb_AmountDue");
  decimal Change = FindDLValue("tb_Change");
```

feel the difference: t*hree evident lines* and two *simple* methods.